# Error when using ] in item title with math mode

Tags: math-mode, lists, description

I am getting the error

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $. \sbox ...hbox {\color@setgroup #2\color@endgroup }
l.6  \item[$]
        $]

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

With the MWB

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[$]$]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

It also fails when using `\(]\)`. Clearly that contained bracket is being matched as the one that closes the optional argument, so how do I prevent that?

Comment: Just write `\item[${]}$]`.

Answer (score 3):

A `]` inside an optional argument with `[]` must be grouped into a `{}` pair (unless the macro is defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` etc. from `xparse`, which is not the case here)

In my point of view there is no need for `$]$` then at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[{]}]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "In my point of view there is no need for `$]$` then at all. " Well the non-minimal case I encountered is actually a math formula that contains `]`, so for my purposes, math mode is needed. But the general concept still works, so thanks. (I always figured math mode provided an implicit grouping, but I guess not.) `[` by itself seems to work just fine either way, though.

Comment: @JAB: You're right that `[` works, but more rather by 'chance' . Grouping does no harm there.